# How difficult is it to direct an email into a gmail recipient's spam folder?

Tags: email

I assume gmail recognizes patterns somehow, but I have no idea how it's done.

What is the easiest way to have an email flagged as spam and directed to the recipient's spam folder? And how confident could the sender be that the email was successfully sent to the spam folder?

Comment: Given that nothing is known about your capabilities and knowledge it is not clear what is easy for you and thus not what is the easiest way for you. But your will likely be considered spam if you do sender spoofing, preferable for domains which have SPF and/or DKIM records but no strict DMARC record. Similar speaking to the MX  from IP with low reputation (like from a typical home user account) will help.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly Gmail supports [GTUBE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTUBE), a test string which will always make the spam filter mark a mail as spam. So including

```
XJS*C4JDBQADN1.NSBN3*2IDNEN*GTUBE-STANDARD-ANTI-UBE-TEST-EMAIL*C.34X
```

In a message body Could do the trick. I don’t use gmail myself so I can’t verify this, but if it is supported it’s one way to guarantee that a mail is marked as spam.

Comment: This works in that it gets caught by the spam filter, but it actually just threw the messages away in my tests (not to Spam, not to Deleted). So that's interesting.